# how do I do a binary selection in a loop with python

Tags: python, binary-search

just a heads up I'm a beginner so the answer is probably pretty easy.

so I'm trying to make a number guessing game where you think of a number between 1 and 100 and then the computer asks you if its x number and you say its either too high or to low

the problem I'm having is after you tell it its too high or too low it just guesses 50 over and over again
I've been googling for about 2 hours and I cant figure out why its doing it

```
   hi = 100
    low = 1
    mid = (hi+low)// 2
    print ("Ok think of a number between 1 and 100.")
    print ("I guess")
    print (mid)
    print ("1.) Too High")
    print ("2.) Too Low")
    g2 = input ("3.) Correct")
    g2 = int(g2)
    hi = int(100)
    low = int(1)
    mid = (hi+low)// 2
while g2 != 3:
    
    if g2 == 1:
        (hi) = (mid) - 1
        print ("I guess")
        print (mid)
        print ("1.) Too High")
        print ("2.) Too Low")
        g2 = input ("3.) Correct")
        g2 = int(g2)
    elif g2 == 2:
        (low) = (mid) + 1
        print ("I guess")
        print (mid)
        print ("1.) Too High")
        print ("2.) Too Low")
        g2 = input ("3.) Correct")
        g2 = int(g2)
```

Comment: looks like some of the code is missing, or it makes no sense that a loop doesn't exit *and print anything in a loop*

Comment: Unless the user enters 3 it won't ever exit, thats not much of a guessing game though

Comment: You never change `mid`.

Comment: Think logically about the steps your code takes. `mid` represents the guess you're going to print, right? Where in your program does that value ever *change*? If you want something to happen every time through a loop, how should you position it in your code?

Comment: You should have googled how to use a debugger - then you could have run your program step by step.

Comment: read the psudocode here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't changed the value of `mid` in your `if` statements.
You are changing the value of `high` and `low` but you are not calculating new `mid` from it, so it always stays `50`.
You just you have to add `mid = (low + hi) // 2` after calculating new `high` or `low` in your `if` statement.